# Swift - does Set(Array) allocate extra space?

Tags: swift, memory, set

I worked on a Leetcode question yesterday. It is described as below:

> Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that
>   each element appear only once and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
>   modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

And here is my solution in Swift, since it requires `in-place with O(1) extra memory`, my question is that does `Set(nums)` requires extra memory, if yes, how much it would takes?

```
class Solution {
    func removeDuplicates(_ nums: inout [Int]) -> Int {
        nums = Array(Set(nums))
        nums.sort() {$0 < $1}
        print(nums)
        return nums.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Set(Array()) or Array(Set())? Not that it matters but it would be nice to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Set(nums)` allocates extra memory.  It could be as large as the array itself if the original values are all unique.

O(1) memory means that your algorithm would only allocate a constant amount of extra memory (probably just 4 or 5 variables) that doesn't depend on the size of the input array.  Imagine the difference in the amount of memory your algorithm would use when the input array has 10 values and when it has 10,000 values.  The `Set` would take up much more memory in the second case, so it isn't O(1).

Hint: Use the fact that the array is sorted to discover duplicates.

Comment: thanks, I get to modify my code now, may using the reference.